# Which time line is later? Star Trek: Voyager's "Living Witness" or Enterprise's "Cold Front/Shockwave"

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-enterprise

Does the episode [*Living Witness*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Living_Witness_(episode)) go the furthest into the Star Trek timeline since it's 700 years into the future, or is [Crewman Daniels'](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Daniels_(Crewman)) timeline the furthest?

Comment: Well, Voyager takes place in the 70s of the 24th century, and Daniels comes from the 31st century, which is indeed the same century as 700 years after Voyager's trip through the Delta Quadrant. Since Voyager happens roughly 3/4th into the 24th century, there is roughly a 3:1 chance that *Living Witness* happens after Daniels' time (provided it is exactly 700 years after current events and not just a rough estimate)...

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/947

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Memory Alpha page for this episode has the following to say:

> Since no date or stardate is given in the episode, the only element that dates the events is Seven of Nine, placing this episode sometime after "The Gift". These events take place at least 700 years after Voyager encountered the Kyrians, placing the activation of the EMH backup and subsequent upheavals in the late 31st century (**approximately 3074**). The final scene, however, takes place no sooner than seven years later, although the docent's monologue, and Quarren's statement that "it could be another seven hundred years," both imply that several generations have passed. It is reasonable to conclude that the final scene takes place as early as **the final years of the 31st century, and as late as the 38th century**. Chronologically, this scene probably takes place farther in the future than any other filmed scene in the entire Star Trek franchise.

So, considering that the events of 'Shockwave' are placed in the 31st century, it is very likely that the last scene, at least, of 'Living Witness' was set after those seen in 'Shockwave'.